# How do I convert Euler Orientations to 2D rotation.

Tags: rotations, orientation

Let me first describe what I am trying to accomplish...

I have a 3D simulated environment that describes the orientation of objects as Euler angles (alpha, beta, and gamma).

[Euler angles convention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgFt2.jpg)

In this environment I have an object with an obvious forwards and backwards direction (lets say a coin with a forwards arrow drawn on it).

Now I want always know what the rotation of this coin is at all times relative to the world.

If the coin is simply rotating around its vertical axis I can measure this as the rotation to the world.

But if the coin was to flip over (now the arrow is on the bottom of it), I have not measured any rotation in the vertical axes, but the arrow is now pointing 180 degrees in the other direction.

I'm not sure if I am being tackling this the wrong way, but I cant seem to find a way of working out something heading from the given Euler Angles.

If anyone knows an easy way to convert between the two, that would be great.

C

Answer (score 1):

People used to Euler parameters know that:

-*"If the coin is simply rotating around its vertical axis"* then at zero pitch, only the roll angle is changing.

-"(...) if the coin was to flip over"*, then at zero roll, the pitch would be increased by 180 degrees.

This convention makes intuitive sense for airplanes that usually don't fly backwards or with the belly up.

I myself grab better intuition from the angle+vector notation. Note that [one angle and a direction vector define any 3D rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem). But it might be easier to convert your Euler angles to [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), as they have better numerical properties. Equations for the conversion are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles). Then, it is straightforward to convert the quaternion to angle+vector.